# How to use bitmap image in Itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF file with a barcode, and to generate this barcode I need to create a BitMap file, but when trying to add this bitmap to the PDF it gives this error:

[image: Image Error]

What could I do?

Comment: Because the .add() function is for adding a text element.

You could try something like this : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/insert-an-image-to-pdf-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Ty! I solved using :  iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);